# List available PricingTiers for Azure SQL Database Resource

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is there any way to read list of available **Pricing Tiers** (SKUs) for [Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/) Resource?

---

The list of availabe SKUs (DTU and vCores) available [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/single/).

But I need to read this list using [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/).

List of SKUs is available for some resources types like (VM, Storage, CognitiveService, etc.).

But this information is **missing** for Azure SQL Database.

*Thanks for any help.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the following PowerShell commandlet after authenticating with Azure - 
`Get-AzSqlServerServiceObjective -Location <LOCATION>`

For example,
`Get-AzSqlServerServiceObjective -Location eastus`

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqlserverserviceobjective?view=azps-4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I believe the API you're looking for is `Capabilities - List By Location`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/capabilities/listbylocation.

I just tried the API for `eastus` location and it gave me all the information though in a bit convoluted way.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.

Comment: That link is broken

Answer (score 0):

This is the current link to the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/2021-02-01-preview/capabilities/list-by-location

An example using the `az rest` command (substitute your `{subscriptionId}`):

```
az rest --method GET --url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/eastus/capabilities?api-version=2021-02-01-preview
```